# Associate Elastic IP with EC2 instance and it broke my Magento install

Tags: amazon-web-services, magento, amazon-ec2

I used an Amazon EC2 AMI from Bitnami to spin up an instance of Magento.  Everything worked fine until I assigned an Elastic IP to it, now the Magento store will not run.  It just times out.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: assign your ip address and open it in browser, if you get a timeout just check your logs and run some dns checks. this could be a magento fault.

Answer (score 0):

Just restart the instance the again and the attached elastic IP will be de associated and attached to the instance again. It will work fine after that.